# Syncing dev/production with git, with a file-based CMS

Tags: php, git, laravel, content-management-system

I am trying to figure out a good development workflow for OctoberCMS, which is a file-based CMS written in Laravel.

I have it set up to deploy via:

```
git push live master
```

However, with OctoberCMS, I need to sync "live" changes back with my local development box (because every time the content gets edited via the CMS, it changes a file). Currently I have no way to "git pull" from the live server.

My post-receive file looks like this:

```
!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/mysite.com --git-dir=/var/repo/mysite.git checkout -f
```

My current setup was based on this [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) article.

Is there a simple way to modify it so I can sync changes back from the live server?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OctoberCMS and the way it saves changes to files, but it sounds like the part that would normally be in the database. If that is the case, what it sounds like you want to do (basically) is automatically make commits to your "live" branch whenever a file changes. That sound right so far?

Comment: Yes that's correct - the files get updated instead of the database. Auto-committing sounds like a possible approach, I will do some Googling on that.

Comment: It might be worth asking in OctoberCMS forums. Auto-committing just doesn't seem like something you should ever have to do. I'd suggest taking the approach that the files are like assets, if at all possible. Could you create a directory where these modified files would go, or are they scattered all throughout the application structure? If you can get them in one place, call it "/files", you could create a symlink and store those on an NFS or look at a cloud drive or something like S3.

Comment: There is a related post on the forums at http://octobercms.com/forum/post/vcs-and-the-cms ... I tried auto-committing, but it got messy quickly with cache files and stuff. I think you're on to the correct approach by syncing just the content folder.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently evaluating a multi instance setup for october cms. With one instance running as dedicated editor instance.

1. Changes in the editor instance are - at the moment - manually pushed to the editor branch of our git repo "git-cms". The idea is to automate this later by using either a cronjob or a file-system watcher.
2. There is a dedicated manual process where we merge the editor branch into the master branch of git-cms. Here we can also inject shared assets like css/js/img files.
3. Based on the git-cms master branch we create new instances (using docker at the moment) for test, production and for the editor.

In a chart our data flow would look like

`editor -> git:editor -> git:master -> editor, test, production`

It's important to know that we explicitly deny access to the backend on the web server level in any instances but the editor. This should help with security but is mostly makes sure we have a clear data flow.

The most obvious limitation of this so far is, that changes in the editor made while the update process is running might be lost when a new instance of the editor is instantiated. This is not an issue for us at the moment as we are small enough to synchronize manually. It probably does not scale well to multiple editors and/or heavy editing. It also introduces an additional delay for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started an OctoberCMS project, and we have decided to gitignore the pages directory. That is the only directory that our users are intended to affect.

I've added the following to the root .gitignore file.

```
/themes/**/pages
```

Comment: but sometimes plugin updated by user from backend which changes plugin files then what will you do ???

Comment: I'm sorry I only used OctoboerCMS briefly 4 years ago and haven't worked with it since. Good luck with your answer!